# spring boot @async with completablefuture for multi-thread

Tags: spring, asynchronous

I am trying to configure a multithreaded environment through spring boot.

Service class

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; j++) {
    threadServiceMethod(i);
}
```

ThreadService class

```
public void threadServiceMethod(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I confirmed that multithreading works by calling threadservice from service.
ex. console = 1 2 3 8 10 5 ....1000

But I want threadservice to select from DB.

So I modified the service.

Service class

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; j++) {
    threadServiceMethod(i);
}
```

ThreadService class

```
public CompletableFuture<List<DTO>> threadServiceMethod(int i) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(DAO method);
}
```

But multithreading doesn't seem to work. Because the logs are output in order.
I don't know if multithreading is working or not. I am using mybatis to make a request to the db.

Comment: Which log, you're talking about? If you're talking about the logs from  `threadServiceMethod` then yes, it will print you the same, you should print log from dao method to verify the concurrency. Also, you need to do multiple runs to identify parallelization.

Comment: Thank you for answering :) Logs appear in order in threadservicemethod

If I need to check logs in dao, should I use async for daomethod as well?